# How can I getting only the number id of the product in shopify using graphql and laravel app

Tags: php, html, laravel, graphql, shopify

This is my route,

```
Route::get('/carts/{numericProductID}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ShopifyController@showProductDetails')
->name('showProductDetails');
```

This is the link to redirect to another page to show/fetch the details of the selected product.

```
<a href="{{ route('showProductDetails', ['numericProductID' => $product['node']['id']]) }}">View Details</a>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue? please provide more context regarding your question.

Comment: @RuelAAlmonia check this sloution

Comment: @Ruel A Almonia please check this

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
use Shopify;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function showProductDetails(Request $request, $numericProductID)
{
    // Build your GraphQL query to fetch the product details
    $query = <<<GRAPHQL
    {
        product(id: $numericProductID) {
            id
            title
            # Add other fields you want to retrieve
        }
    }
    GRAPHQL;

    // Make the GraphQL request to Shopify
    $response = Shopify::graph($query);

    // Parse the response JSON
    $productData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    // Extract the numeric product ID
    $numericID = $productData['data']['product']['id'];

    // You can now use $numericID in your view or return it as needed
    // For example, return a view with the product details
    return view('product_details', ['product' => $productData['data']['product']]);
}
```

> in view file

```
<a href="{{ route('showProductDetails', ['numericProductID' => $product['id']]) }}">View Details</a>
```